# Want to include voice recognition to open my grid view icon in my android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, speech-recognition

I made a grid view in my app now I want to include voice recognition in it so that:
when user will say "home" then home icon will open:

I'm beginner in android development so plz give me a detailed answer:

I made a voice.java class and uses Recognizer intent , ACTION_RECOGNIZER_SPEECH and also onactivityResult() method from a tutorial I i cant able to link it with my icons.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridview;
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 



    Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.home);
    Bitmap facultyIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.faculty);
    Bitmap courcesIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.cources);
    Bitmap admissionIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.admission);
    Bitmap newsIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.news);
    Bitmap acheivmentsIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.award);
    Bitmap cornerIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.corner);
    Bitmap amenitiesIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.amenities);
    Bitmap societiesIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.socities);
    Bitmap timeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.time_table);
    Bitmap eventsIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.events);
    Bitmap contactIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.contact);

    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon, "Home","http://bit.ly.com/"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(courcesIcon, "Courses","http://bit.ly.com/courses.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(facultyIcon, "Faculty","http://bit.ly.com/faculty.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(admissionIcon, "Admission","http://bit.ly.com/admission.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(newsIcon, "News","http://bit.ly.com/news.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(acheivmentsIcon, "Acheivments","http://bit.ly.com/achievement.html"));       
    gridArray.add(new Item(cornerIcon, "Student Corner","http://bit.ly.com/student-corner.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(amenitiesIcon, "Amenities","https://www.google.co.in/"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(societiesIcon, "Societies","http://bit.ly.com/socities.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(timeIcon, "Time Table","http://bit.ly.com/time-tables.html"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(eventsIcon, "Events","https://www.google.co.in/"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(contactIcon, "Contact Us","http://bit.ly.com/directories.html"));

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
    gridview.setAdapter(customGridAdapter); 
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String url=gridArray.get(arg2).getWebUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.//package name.SECONDACTIVITY");
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });
    }


}
```

}